# linq->SQL orderby descending not working

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

```
var Customer = (from c in DNAContextSQL.Customers
                                where c.LastName != ""
                                orderby c.PKID_Customer descending
                                select new
                                {
                                    c.PKID_Customer,
                                    c.OrganizationName,
                                    c.FirstName,
                                    c.LastName,
                                    c.Phone,
                                    c.Extension
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I know this is basic.  I can't find any good reason why it's not working though.  The queries sent to SQL Profiler don't seem to have an `order by` clause in them.

Any ideas?

I can get it to work with `.OrderByDescending(...)` but would like to know the reason behind this madness.

Comment: You are DNA tracking your customers? That's pretty hardcore. I imagine they get your samples when you push the little swipe card / pin machine. Edit - "5% off with blood sample, this friday!"

Comment: Why are you using .Distinct()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinct is probably messing up the order by try calling the orderBy after the distinct()

```
var Customer = (from c in DNAContextSQL.Customers
                where c.LastName != ""
                select new
                   {
                      c.PKID_Customer,
                      c.OrganizationName,
                      c.FirstName,
                      c.LastName,
                      c.Phone,
                      c.Extension
                    }
                ).Distinct().OrderByDescending(c=>c.PKID_Customer).ToList();
```

This is happening because you first select a set of rows that are ordered by the PKID_Customer (and they are ordered until you call the distinct() method), and after that the Distinct() method rearranges them into a new distinct unordered set of records.

Comment: That works and is what I have right now in the code.  I would like to know why having `orderby c.PKID_Customer descending` is NOT working. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah. Interesting.  So taking out the .Distinct() should fix it then.  Thanks! (and sure enough, it did.)

Comment: if you don't need the distinct it will work withouth the added .OrderByDescending()